# SHarePoint list calculation qualified not weekend

Tags: sharepoint-2013, calculated-columns

In my SharePoint list, I have a field containing one of three possible values.  Depending on the value and a secondary field containing the date submitted, a due date will be calculated (adding 1, 3 or 14 days) to the date submitted but this date cannot land on a weekend and must not count the days as workdays.

I have tried numerous if, and, weekend combinations with no luck.  My co-workers are also stumped.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: This link might help  you. But it works only for +2days. You need to modify it. Goodluck. https://www.c5insight.com/Resources/Blog/tabid/88/entryid/567/2-easy-ways-to-calculate-working-days-inside-a-sharepoint-workflow.aspx.

Comment: Thank you, I'll play later.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a column named "Days" and a column named "TheDate" where "Days" contains the 1, 3, 14 or a formula to select one of those values.

```
= TheDate+Days + IF(WEEKDAY(TheDate+Days)=1,1,0) + IF(WEEKDAY(TheDate+Days)=7,2,0)
```

This adds the "Days" to "TheDate" and then:

- checks to see if the new date is a Sunday, and if so, adds 1
- checks to see if the new date is a Saturday, and if so, adds 2